# Tikz node labels more below than below

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the tikz package. Is there a typografical/semantic/other reason why

```
\draw(2,0.6) node[\label=below:$b_1$]{} -- (2,4);
```

produces a label more below than

```
\draw(2,0.6) node[below]{$b_1$};
```

For example, try the following code to notice the difference.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw (2,0.6) node[below]{$b_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}`

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw (2,0.6) node[label=below:$b_1$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the first case the one node is placed below the point with content `$b_1$`. In the second case a node without content (but still with positive height) is placed at the point and a *second* node with `$b_1$` is placed below it.

Maybe a picture helps:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) circle (0.05) node[below,draw]{$b_1$};
    \fill (1,0) circle (0.05) node[label=below:$b_1$,draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Interesting. That means that the "multiple" labels is done by placing extra nodes.

Comment: Ah! It was right in front of my face. In the pgfmanual it says "This option is given to a node and it causes another node
to be added next to the node where the option is given."